# Unable to change default headers httpd on Amazon Machine Image

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, laravel, amazon-web-services

I have an error with my aws ec2-server with the standard Amazon Machine Image.
The OPTIONS call from my angular js frontend gets following response from my laravel backend:

```
Route::options('{all}', function () {

$response = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::make('');

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) && in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], ['http://localhost:8090'])) {
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
} else {
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', url()->current());
}
$response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
$response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
$response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
$response->header('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff');

return $response;
});
```

On my local XAMPP I get the correct response Headers from the Options Call. But on my AWS Server it returns just some default headers
[image]

Do I have to activate something or set the Headers somewhere else?